# How can I create a goto expression in xtext?

Tags: eclipse, grammar, dsl, xtext, go-to-definition

I want to create a goto expression as follows

```
//label
 <bb 2> :

//goto
goto <bb 2>;
```

The following grammar works fine for a simple ID. I have no idea how to reference the `<ID INT>`
in the goto expression.

```
Goto returns Goto:
    {Goto}
    'goto' goto+=[Label]  ';'
;

LabelDef returns LabelDef:
    {LabelDef}
    label+= Label ':'
    ;

Label returns Label:
    {Label}
    name= ID
    ;
```

Do have any idea how to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the feature you are looking for is a DataType rule

```
Goto returns Goto:
    {Goto}
    'goto' goto+=[Label|IDandINT]  ';'
;

LabelDef returns LabelDef:
    {LabelDef}
    label+= Label ':'
    ;

Label returns Label:
    {Label}
    name= IDandINT
    ;
IDandINT: ID INT;
```

you may also introduce / customize DefaultTerminalConverters/IValueConverter for the datatype rule to normalize whitespace

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when generating I wasn't having the result I was looking for because of xtext. I discovered that when I created a new project. The following sub-grammar works fine.

`Goto returns Goto:
 {Goto}
 'goto' goto = [Label|QualifiedName]  ';' '[INV]'
;

LabelDef returns LabelDef:
 {LabelDef}
 name = Label
 ;



Label returns Label:
 {Label}
   name = QualifiedName ':'
 ;
 
QualifiedName:
 '<' ID INT '>' ; `

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a terminal that is essentially "ID INT" and then use it to crossreference your Label.
I think this is going to be a lot of work just to be able to allow "spaces" in your labels. Why not simply rely on terminal "ID" and users may name them "bb2" if they wish?